# Numbers 'poetics' 1 and 2019

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, solution-verification

> One number is called 'poetic' when it can be represented of only one form how $2^a+2^b+2^c$ such that $a\ge b \ge c\ge 0.$ How many  poetic numbers are between $1$ and $2019?$

**Attempt:** I separate in cases, I find that every $2^k$ with $k\ge2 , 2^k + 1$ with $k\ge1$ and every case with $a>b>c$

My final answer was $184$. Check that please .

$a\ge b\ge c\ge 0$

Numbers of form $2^k, k\ge 2$ and $2^k+1,k\ge 1$ are also unique re presentable

$2^k=2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+2^{k-2}$

$2^{k}+1=2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}+2^0$

Comment: How do you arrive at $184$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde here

Comment: You forgot $6=2^2+2^0+2^0$, for example.

Comment: What do you suggest to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a\ge b\ge c\ge0$. But there is also a requirement that the representation is unique. So for example: 6 does not count because it is $4+1+1$ and also $2+2+2$.

Indeed, we have

(1): $2^a+2^a+2^b=2^{a+1}+2^{b-1}+2^{b-1}$ for $b\ge1$ and

(2): $2^a+2^b+2^b=2^{a-1}+2^{a-1}+2^{b+1}$ for $a>b+1$. [For $a=b+1$ the two expressions are identical]

We have $2^{11}=2048$, so $a\le10$ and if $a=10$, then we need $b<10$. Also if $a=10,b=9$, then $c<9$.

So for $a=10$ we can have $b=9$ and then $0\le c\le 8$, giving 9 possibilities. If $b=8$ then (2) requires $0\le c<8$ giving 8 possibilities. And so on, down to $b=1$ for which we must have $c=0$. So in total $a=10$ gives $1+2+\dots+9=45$.

For $a=9$ and $b=9$ only $c=0$ is allowed because of (1). For $b=8$ we can have $0\le c\le 8$ (9 poss). For $b=7$ we can have $0\le c\le 6$ (because (2) rules out $c=7$), giving 7 poss. For $b=6$ we have 6 poss, and so on down to 1 poss for $b=1$. So in total $a=9$ gives $(1+2+\dots+7)+9+1=38$.

Similarly for $a=8$ we get $1+2+\dots+6+9=30$, for $a=7$ we get $1+2+\dots+5+8=23$. For $a=6$ we get $1+2+\dots+4+7=17$. For $a=5$ we get $1+2+3+6=12$. For $a=4$ we get $1+2+5=8$, for $a=3$ we get $1+4=5$. For $a=2$ we get 3 (check: $9=4+4+1,8=4+2+2,7=4+2+1$). For $a=1$ we get 2 and for $a=0$ we get 1.

So grand total $45+38+30+23+17+12+8+5+3+2+1=184$.

Comment: You missed $30$ (for $a=8$) in the final sum.

Comment: @CYAries Many thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

As $2^{11}>2047>2020>2^{10}+2^9$, there are no poetic numbers from $2020$ to $2047$.

All poetic numbers from $1$ to $2047$ actually lie between $1$ and $2019$.

Integers in this range can be written as binary numbers of no more than $11$ digits.

A poetic number should have at most three $1$'s in the digits when it is expressed as a binary number.

A binary number with exactly three $1$'s in the digits when it is expressed as a binary number is clearly a poetic number.

A binary number with exactly two $1$'s in the digits when it is expressed as a binary number is a poetic number if and only if the last digit is $1$. [Note: $2^a+2^b=2^{a-1}+2^{a-1}+2^b=2^a+2^{b-1}+2^{b-1}$.]

A binary number with exactly one $1$ in the digits when it is expressed as a binary number is a poetic number if and only if the last  two digits are $0$'s. [Note: $2^a=2^{a-1}+2^{a-2}+2^{a-2}$.]

So the number of poetic numbers from $1$ to $2019$ is $\displaystyle \binom{11}{3}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{9}{1}=184$.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused with the answers

Comment: My answer is the same as yours and I checked it with Excel.  There are $184$ integers which can be expressed as $2^a+2^b+2^c$ with $a\ge b\ge 0$ in a unique way.  There are $45$ integers that can be expressed in two ways (e.g. $6=4+1+1=2+2+2$, $10=8+1+1=4+4+2$, etc.) These $45$ integers are those with two $1$'s in the digits and the last digit is $0$ when it is expressed as a binary number.  The count is $\binom{10}{2}=45$.

Comment: +1 Yes, that is a neater answer than mine!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Since $a\ge b\ge c\ge0 $ , it follows that :

$$2019\ge2^a+2^b+2^c \ge 3\cdot2^c \implies  9\ge c$$

And trivial to notice that $a\le10$

We only have $10$ cases for $c$ which can be checked by hand .

Comment: I don't see how you rule out the disallowed numbers such as 6 (disallowed because 2+2+2=4+1+1).

Comment: @almagest oops. Almost forgot about the uniquness of the numbers . But nevertheless , since we are checking each cases by hand , we can manually remove such numbers .

Comment: It is more arduous than I thought - I think it needs checking with a short piece of code.